# SQL query is not sending data to database

Tags: php, mysql

Hello guys I am trying to apply this query but values are not saving in my database. I have tried a lot but I am not able to fix it. Please Help me. Thanks in advance

```
if($_POST) {
    $lecturer_id = $_SESSION["lecturer_id"];
    $game_name= $_POST['game_name'];
    mysql_query("insert into games(game_name, lecturer_id) values ('$game_name', '$lecturer_id')");
    $input_type = $_POST['type'];
    if($input_type=='multiple_choice') {
        $question= $_POST['quest'];
        $val1= $_POST['value1'];
        $val2= $_POST['value2'];
        $val3= $_POST['value3'];
        $val4= $_POST['value4'];
        //echo $question;
        // echo $val4;
        mysql_query("insert into subgames(game_id, input_id, statement, option1,    option2, option3, option4) values ((SELECT id 
        FROM games
        WHERE game_name = '$game_name'), '$input_type', '$question', '$val1', '$val2', '$val3', '$val4'");
    } elseif($input_type=='input_field') {
        $question= $_POST['quest'];
        $answer= $_POST['ans'];
    }
} else {
echo "Not Submitted";
}
```

Comment: Any error messages we can work with?

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to the database properly? Could you post the code that connects you to the database?

Comment: since you are starting out, get into mysqli or pdo, as you will be vulnerable to sql injection attacks with what you certainly have. [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174) ... So just throw it out. Use prepared stmts

Comment: Have you session_start() before you use $_SESSION?

Comment: Beside your question you need to use Prepared Statements instead of this way of querying you are so open to SQL injection

Comment: No Error messages. And yes session_start() is added. Database connection is working properly as i am using the same database file for all other things and they are working fine

Comment: @dan08 no error messages

Comment: You _should_ [pick another API](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) to connect to your mysql server as the mysql_* extension is deprecated not present in the upcoming release of php 7. You _must_ add some kind of error handling. For the mysql_* functions that would be checking each and every return value; if it's FALSE something went wrong in which case mysql_error() can tell you more details.

Comment: @HarishTalanki i am using the same database connection file for the whole project and everything is fine but on this page my values are not getting saved please help me

Comment: Even though you use the same database connection, when you run the DML queries (insert or delete), you need to [commit](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.commit.php).

Comment: I did not commit and i don't know how to do this. can you please help me?

Comment: Click on "commit" in my previous comment.. It will take to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to check the `mysql_error()?`

Add this code:

```
echo mysql_error();
```

Then post the error.

Comment: After applying this(echo mysql_error($query);) i am getting this error

      Warning: mysql_error() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\class\lecturer\newGame.php on line 216
Add Input

Comment: please help me i am stuck here

Comment: @MuhammadUmar Follow the instructions better.  Look at Edmhar's code vs what you applied.

Comment: @MuhammadUmar don't add `$query` just `echo mysql_error();`

Comment: @James i have applied this query on my phpmyadmin and i am getting this error
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`class`.`games`, CONSTRAINT `games_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`lecturer_id`) REFERENCES `lecturer` (`id`))

Comment: @Edmhar i have this query to my phpmyadmin and i am getting this error
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`class`.`games`, CONSTRAINT `games_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`lecturer_id`) REFERENCES `lecturer` (`id`))

Comment: @MuhammadUmar: You're getting this error because you're trying to add/update a row to table that does not have a valid value. It's either `lecturer_id` or `lecturer (id))` doesn't exist in the table.

Comment: Try to check your spelling of your columns and like I said try to run the `echo mysql_error();`

Comment: @Edmhar I have added this and i am getting this error
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`class`.`games`, CONSTRAINT `games_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`game_type_id`) REFERENCES `gametype` (`id`))

Comment: @MuhammadUmar check the spelling one by one of your columns, tables look if they match,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94263/discussion-between-muhammad-umar-and-edmhar).

Comment: @James please help me i am stuck

Answer (score 0):

```
    Step 1:-
     SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name:

    It will show table details

    | table_name | CREATE TABLE `table_name` (
     `id` int(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
     `key_column` smallint(5) unsigned default '1',
      KEY `key_column` (`key_column`),
      CONSTRAINT `table_name_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`key_column`) REFERENCES 
     `second_table` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL
      ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |

     Step2:-
     ALTER TABLE table_name DROP KEY `key_column`;

     Step3:-
     ALTER TABLE table_name DROP FOREIGN KEY `table_name_ibfk_1`;
```